# Retrieving data using php that's stored in MySql as varbinary

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just made a few changes to my tables changing `varchar` to `varbinary` after reading about it's advantages, and seeing that media wiki also use it.

So I created a table called `test`

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `user` VARBINARY(255) NOT NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and inserted

`insert into test (user) values ('Norman');`

`Result :0X4E6F726D616E`

then

`select user from test;`

`Result :0X4E6F726D616E`

How do I get data from `user` in human readable form? How does this whole varbinary thing work?

I see MediWiki use it all over their database, but still get data out in a form that's readable. How is this done?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What are the advantages using `varbinary` for strings?

Comment: @juergen d, I recommend to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978484/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-varbinary-over-varchar-here

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. I wouldn't have any advantage but but the disadvantage not being able to compare using a collation. Saving some bytes doesn't matter to me.