# Get top 1 results from sql results based on the highest version in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a basic query where I see a list of usernames and versions of an app they are using:

```
Username AppVersion  Email           First Name
-------- ----------  -----           ----------
user1    2.3         user1@aol.com   User 1
user1    2.4         user1@aol.com   User 1
user1    2.5         user1@aol.com   User 1
user2    2.3         user2@aol.com   User 2
user2    2.4         user2@aol.com   User 2
user3    2.4         user3@aol.com   User 3
user3    2.5         user3@aol.com   User 3
```

My SQL is:

```
SELECT TOP 100 LoginLog.SalesRepID, LoginLog.AppVersion FROM  LoginLog
GROUP BY LoginLog.SalesRepID, LoginLog.AppVersion
ORDER BY SalesRepID, LoginLog.AppVersion DESC
```

But what I really want from this list is the newest version of the app that the user is on, so my result would really be:

```
Username AppVersion  Email           First Name
-------- ----------  -----           ----------
user1  2.5         user1@aol.com   User 1
user2  2.4         user2@aol.com   User 2
user3  2.5         user3@aol.com   User 3
```

How do I modify this query to show that kind of result?

### EDIT:

I apologize, I was not clear enough here - I tried to simplify my question and should not have.  There are a couple of additional columns in this example I left out- #FACEPALM

See revised above - sorry everyone!!!

Comment: What's the data type for "AppVersion"?

Comment: Where is Username on your query? you should group by username and get max of appversion

Comment: @Slee: It doesn't matter what columns you want if you use the `CTE`+`ROW_NUMBER` approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a common table expression with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Username, 
                AppVersion, 
                RN = Row_number() 
                       OVER ( 
                         partition BY username 
                         ORDER BY Cast('/' + Replace(AppVersion, '.', '/') + '/' 
                       AS 
                       HIERARCHYID) 
                       DESC 
                       ) 
         FROM   loginlog) 
SELECT Username, AppVersion FROM  CTE
WHERE  RN = 1 
ORDER BY UserName
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46249/4/0)

Credits for the version sort here:

[How Can I Sort A 'Version Number' Column Generically Using a SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query)

Comment: +1, but you forgot to order by `UserName` on your final `SELECT`.

Comment: @Cory: Thanks, edited. However, also edited to use the version sort which i've found [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query)(i'm usually on sql-server 2005).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `[AppVersion]` column is a string, I've added some conversion. When using aggregate functions such as `MAX()`, those columns should be excluded from your `GROUP BY` clause. Also, to get the `ORDER BY` in the right order, the same conversion should go in that clause as well.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    SalesRepID
   ,MAX(CONVERT(float, LoginLog.AppVersion))
FROM  
    LoginLog
GROUP BY 
    SalesRepID
ORDER BY 
    SalesRepID, CONVERT(float, LoginLog.AppVersion)
```

**EDIT** This won't work if the application version numbers include minor revisions (e.g. `3.4.2`). Tim's approach will work better in that situation.

Comment: I had to revise my question, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming AppVersion is a numeric-type field, use the MAX() function, and group on ONLY the SalesRepIDs:

```
SELECT TOP 100 LoginLog.SalesRepID, MAX(LoginLog.AppVersion)
FROM  LoginLog
GROUP BY LoginLog.SalesRepID
ORDER BY SalesRepID
```