# Sort Release Versions that contain two different decimal places

Tags: c#, sql, sorting

Currently I get the `Release Version` from a website using Selenium and it is stored as a string.

The Release Versions are `14.14`,`14.14.4`,`14.15`,`14.15.1`,`14.15.2` etc.

I need to sort them using C# and the Database Admin needs to be able to sort them using SQL. All of the `Release Version` items are currently stored as strings.

I do all my SQL stuff using LINQ to SQL if that matters.

What is the best way to sort them in both C# and SQL? As strings? Or should I convert them? What data type would be used if converting them?

Comment: To avoid having to write sorting code in both C# and SQL, you could start saving the versions with fixed width numbering `014.015.001` so lexical sort works naturally in both, but obviously you may not want or have control over that.

Comment: In C#, you could just provide a custom IComparer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534863.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you could store them as (or at least convert to) `Version` which also supports correct sorting:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "14.14", "14.14.4", "14.15", "14.15.1", "14.15.2" };
var versions = strings.Select(v => Version.Parse(v)).ToList();
versions.Sort();  // or OrderBy in the LINQ query above
```

Here's a question which shows how to sort versions in the database: [How Can I Sort A 'Version Number' Column Generically Using a SQL Server Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with converting it back and forth, then convert the version to an int. since there are max 3 parts for the version, just convert it to {0} * 10000 + {1} * 100 + {2}