# Using SORTORDER to sort x.x.x values SQL

Tags: sql, sorting

Let's say I'm trying to sort the Column "numbers"

numbers =
 
"1,
1.1, 
1.1.1,
1.1.2,
1.1.10"

When I do

ORDER BY NUMBERS , the resulting sorted column is

numbers =
 
"1,
1.1, 
1.1.1,
1.1.10, 
1.1.2"

I know the original column is already sorted, but that's only for this example... Why does .10 show up before .2?

Comment: (assuming the numbers' column type is text). Because 1.1.10 is before 1.1.2 in the alphabetical order. Quoting wikipedia: The result of placing a set of words or strings in alphabetical order is that all the strings beginning with the same letter are grouped together; and within that grouping all words beginning with the same two-letter sequence are grouped together; and so on. The system thus tends to maximize the number of common initial letters between adjacent words.

Comment: @vc74 - i would post that as an answer... because that's all the question really asks, why?  not necessarily how to fix or change.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Dun!

Comment: If you want a solution: [How Can I Sort A 'Version Number' Column Generically Using a SQL Server Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 1):

(assuming the numbers' column type is text).

Because 1.1.10 is before 1.1.2 in the alphabetical order.

Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order): The result of placing a set of words or strings in alphabetical order is that all the strings beginning with the same letter are grouped together; and within that grouping all words beginning with the same two-letter sequence are grouped together; and so on. The system thus tends to maximize the number of common initial letters between adjacent words.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but you can try this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(numbers, 3) as int), CAST(PARSENAME(numbers, 2) as int), CAST(PARSENAME(numbers, 1) as int)
```