# how to manipulate string column of numbers separated by dots using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column of `nvarchar(255)` type that represents software version 
numbers:

```
  VersionNumber
 ---------------

    1.0.0.505
    1.0.0.506
    1.0.0.507
    1.0.0.508
    1.0.0.509
    1.0.1.2
```

**I need to extract the maximum version number** (the min version number in the example above is 1.0.0.505 and the max version number is 1.0.1.2, values arranged from the smallest to the highest).

in order to explain exactly what i need - if i could use imperative programming language i think i would do something like that to detect the max version number:

- lets say version number is d.c.b.a.
- i would separate each version number to four different variables: a b
  c d
- that i will sum each series.
- a will be summed by tens
- b will be summed by hundreds
- c will be summed by thousands
- d will be summed by milions

than the maximum total sum of each Max(a+b+c+d) will be the max version.
**but what is the technic to achieve something like that in sql?**

Comment: HIERARCHYID can help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query

Comment: @AlexK. wow! i have tried a lot to search before asking and did not found it , that is exactly what i need. thank you.

Comment: for future readers: based on @AlexK. link that is the solution: `select TOP 1 VersionNumber from Users order by (cast('/' + replace(VersionNumber , '.', '/') + '/' as hierarchyid)) DESC;`

Comment: You can post that as an answer & accept it to close this question.

Comment: Why not `MAX(VersionNumber)`? Under what circumstances does that not get you the correct result?

Comment: @AlanBurstein with MAX() 1.2 > 1.10 for example

Comment: @AlanBurstein because its `varchar` column I did not even think of trying it, i see its not throwing an exception...but are you sure it will return the correct result under all conditions?

Comment: @jonathana I posted my answer to the duplicated question.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi i have tried your solution, its working, very creative to do that imperaive code with sql, thank you for your time and effort!! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for future readers: based on @AlexK. link that is the solution:

`select TOP 1 VersionNumber from Users order by (cast('/' + replace(VersionNumber , '.', '/') + '/' as hierarchyid)) DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select max(replace(version,'.','')) from yourtable
```

Comment: How would that rank `1.23.4.5` versus `1.2.34.5`?