# Sql Max() not returning correct value for column of type varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sql table with 2 column namely ReqNo and Sr.No of type bigint and varchar as in below an example and query. I am trying to get the maximum value of the column Sr.No wrt ReqNo but I am, getting wrong value. Kindly suggest me to correct the query.

```
Request No  Sr.No
 120184       1
 120184       1.1
 120184       1.10
 120184       1.2
 120184       1.3
 120184       1.4
 120184       1.5
 120184       1.6
 120184       1.7
 120184       1.8
 120184       1.9
```

Query

```
select MAX(cast(SrNo as float)) as SrNo 
from tbl_Material_Req 
where Req_No='120184'
```

The above query returns 1.9 as max value. But the table above has 1.10 which is greater than 1.9

What I have tried

1. MAX(cast(SrNo as decimal(10,2)))
2. SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(SrNo,3, LEN(SrNo)) AS float)) from tbl_Material_Req where Req_No='120184'
3. select max(Convert(float, SrNo)) from tbl_Material_Req where isnumeric(SrNo) = 1 and Req_No='120184'

But the above doesn’t work for me.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: 1.10 = 1.1 < 1.9 - you need to parse your serial number into two bits

Comment: This solution seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474870/how-can-i-sort-a-version-number-column-generically-using-a-sql-server-query

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Actually, the number `1.9` is larger than the number `1.10` (which is simply `1.1`), and the text `'1.9'` is larger than the text `'1.10'` as well, due to alphabetical sorting.

Comment: @BartHofland yes, you're correct on this one. my mistake